# Can we get hiking boots and jackets for rent at Jungfraujoch?

Tags: switzerland, gear, rental, mountains

We are going to visit Jungfraujoch in the first week of June. It has been recommended that we have hiking boots and warm jackets to keep out the wind. I would like to know if the boots and the jacket is available for rent. We would want to avoid buying the equipment as we need it only for those two days, and want to avoid carrying it throughout our trip.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you really need this. If you want to go out and walk on the snow etc, you should definitely take some winter boots, but if you just want to go see the view and stand on the viewing platform to take pictures some other sensible shoes (sports shoes) should also do the trick. The same goes for jacket. A lot of areas are actually inside buildings and heated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - it seems to be possible to rent gear. The [local Swiss tourist board](http://jungfrauregion.ch/en/Holidays/SUMMER/Rental) website gives a list of a few shops in the area (click on Explore). The first, Wyss Sport in Kleine Scheidegg offers rental of jackets and "shoes" for the trip to the Jungfraujoch - and their shop is near to the start of the Jungfraujoch Railway.

There are a few other shops listed in other towns that offer rental of boots and sticks; these might be a better bet if you are staying in one of those towns.